How can you evaluate rust expressions in LLDB that reference external crates?
How can I evaluate Rust expressions in LLDB?  It feels really broken as I can't evaluate any expressions that reference external crates.  What do I do to get this to work?
It will work for core/std libraries and structures I define myself.  But why won't chrono or decimal work?
use chrono::Utc;

pub struct T {
    a: usize
}

impl T {
    pub fn new() -> T {
        T {
            a: 1
        }
    }
}


// This works
fn t1() -> T {
    T::new()
}

// This works
fn t2() -> std::time::Duration {
    std::time::Duration::new(1, 0)
}

// This does not work
fn t3() -> chrono::DateTime<chrono::Utc> {
    chrono::Utc::now()
}

// This works
fn t4() -> i64 {
    chrono::Utc::now().timestamp()
}

// This works
fn t5() -> ordered_float::NotNan<f64> {
    ordered_float::NotNan::new(4.0).unwrap()
}


// This does not work
fn t6() -> rust_decimal::Decimal {
    rust_decimal::Decimal::MAX
}


const D: &'static rust_decimal::Decimal = &rust_decimal::Decimal::MAX;

// This works
fn t7() -> &'static rust_decimal::Decimal {
    D
}




fn main() {
    let a = t1();
    let b = t2();
    let c = t3();
    let d = t4();
    let e = t5();
    let f = t6();
    let g = t7();

}

It's very odd:
(lldb) expression t1()
(debug::T)  = (a = 1)

(lldb) expression t2()
(core::time::Duration)  = {
  secs = 0
  nanos = (0 = 0)
}

(lldb) expression t3()
error: function call failed

(lldb) expression t4()
(i64)  = 1717610601

I've tried with a few different versions of lldb but no luck in getting common modules to work.

lldb doesn't have direct expression evaluation support for Rust.  Unlike for C/C++/ObjC/Swift, there is not a Rust language plugin that knows the Rust syntax and can parse & execute expressions in a Rust context.  lldb has a plugin architecture for implementing this, and at one point there was a fork of lldb that had a Rust expression parser, but that was never submitted to the mainline lldb.
The current support for Rust expression evaluation in lldb consists of setting a "Rust is pretty much like C++" flag, and then Rust expressions are parsed and executed by the C++ parser with the C++ ABI and linkage model.  That mostly works, but there are bound to be places where the differences between Rust & C++ actually matter.  It's not altogether surprising that cross module references is one of these areas.
